# No variable $config found in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am getting this error

> No variable $config found in \app\Config\global_constant.php

Please help me to fix this issue.

This is my global_constant file:

```
<?php 
include_once('../../global_constant.php');
include_once('../../settings.php');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define a blank array like this in your global constant file

```
$config     =   array();
```